# When I use Latex packages (package bm) in Rmarkdown, how can it be rendered to html output?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

When I use Latex packages (package bm) in Rmarkdown, how can it be rendered to Html output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages that output LaTeX math mode (single equations and arrays of equations) work fine if you put `results='asis'` in the chunk header.  General rendering of LaTeX into html documents is not possible to the best of my knowledge.  That's why it's worth having an `html` method whenever you write a `latex` method (I do this a lot in the `Hmisc` package).

Comment: Hello, I installed "tools" packages using tlmgr and set header-includes:
- \usepackage{bm}  in .Rmd file, but $\bm{\sigma}$ can't be rendered. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You should be able to just type `$\sigma$` and html reports will automatically use `mathjax` to nicely render the math.